# How to make <tab> work in org mode when combined with evil mode?

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, evil

In `evil` mode, I would like `C-i` not to work as a tab key, which is the default behavior in Emacs. Also, I would not have the default `vi` behavior simulated in Emacs `evil` by `evil-jump-forward`, but instead I would like to have `C-i` work as the `scroll-down-command`.

Then, since `C-i` is mapped to `<tab>` by default, and I would like `<tab>` work as the usual `indent-for-tab-command`, I need to bind `<tab>` also. Here is a minimal setup:

```
(setq package-load-list
      '((evil t)
        (undo-tree t)
        (goto-chg t)))

(package-initialize)
(require 'evil)
(evil-mode 1)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-i") 'scroll-down-command)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "<tab>") 'indent-for-tab-command)
```

The problem now is that this seems to confuse `org-mode`. I think `<tab>` in `org-mode` only works correctly if `<tab>` is not bound, in that case `org-mode` will rebind it locally to `org-cycle`.

So now I am not able to expand subtrees in org-mode. In fact, in `org-mode` the `<tab>` key is bound to `indent-for-tab-command` instead of the desired `org-cycle` command. How to solve this problem?

Note that the solution provided in [Emacs, org-mode, evil-mode - TAB key not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22878668/2173773) does not work, since I rebind the `<tab>` key.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not 100% clear what you want the <kbd>tab</kbd> key to do
when you're in `org-mode`.

What you have done is to bind <kbd>tab</kbd> in `evil`'s "global"
`normal`-state keymap.  If you're in `normal` state in an `org`
buffer, <kbd>tab</kbd> will do what *you* bound it to do, not to
the default `org-cycle`.

If you want <kbd>tab</kbd> to invoke `org-cycle` in `org` buffers
when you're in normal state, you can:

```
(evil-define-key 'normal org-mode-map (kbd "<tab>") #'org-cycle)
```

Comment: Great! This works perfectly. Nice to learn about the `evil-define-key` function.