# evil-mode unmap TAB key from evil-jump-forward

Tags: key-bindings, evil

I use `evil-mode` and `evil-collection`.

The `TAB` key is bound/maped (?) to `evil-jump-forward`. I do not know which of the evil-packages or parts did this. I do not use this function.

I need the `TAB` key for `org-mode`. How do I unmap/unbound a key when using `use-package`?

```
;; === EVIL
(use-package evil
  :init
  (setq evil-want-integration t)
  (setq evil-want-keybinding nil)
  :config
  (evil-mode 1)
  ;; Use visual line motions even outside of visual-line-mode buffers
  (evil-global-set-key 'motion "j" 'evil-next-visual-line)
  (evil-global-set-key 'motion "k" 'evil-previous-visual-line)
  ;; Set "normal" vi-mode in specific buffers
  (evil-set-initial-state 'messages-buffer-mode 'normal)
  (evil-set-initial-state 'dashboard-mode 'normal)
  )

(use-package evil-collection
  :after evil
  :config
  (evil-collection-init)
  )
```

This question is not specific about `evil` or `org`. It could be any other key or package. This case is just an example where it could be usefull to unmap/unbound a keybinding. And **the question** is how to do that in the context of `use-package`.

Comment: It mostly likely has something to do with the issue with `<tab>` and `C-i`. See [this link](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17509/how-to-distinguish-c-i-from-tab). To check for yourself, what does `C-h k C-i` output?

Comment: https://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/emacs-evil-org-tab/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make <tab> work in org mode when combined with evil mode?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28222/how-to-make-tab-work-in-org-mode-when-combined-with-evil-mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand the details here but when setting this variable for `evil-mode` the <kbd>TAB</kbd> works in `org-mode`.

```
(setq evil-want-C-i-jump nil)
```

Comment: Does anyone know why this fixes it lol wow