# Why I can't fold (org-cycle) in non-GUI?

Tags: org-mode, terminal-emacs, gui

It seems using non-GUI is much much faster when working with very long org-files.

However I can't `org-cycle` with `TAB` key. (See image below).

[image]

What is happening?
My best guess is: when `TAB` pressed instead of `Org`, `EVIL` uses for it's keybinding (`evil-jump-forward` as shown in bottom right of image). Then why is that?

Comment: with the help of [this question's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/69282/evil-mode-unmap-tab-key-from-evil-jump-forward). I can turn off `evil-jump-forward` and can `org-cycle`. However, I still want `evil-jump-forward` to work other non-orgmode buffers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll try to answer why pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key leads to different results when you're using the Emacs GUI vs. Emacs in a terminal.

`org-cycle` is bound to both `<tab>` and `TAB` (at least in my and probably your version of org (see ). `evil-jump-forward` is bound to just `TAB`. (Yes, these are [subtly different](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9631/what-is-the-difference-between-tab-and-tab)!)

`<tab>` is how Emacs interprets the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key in GUI Emacs. Normally, (but not always), in GUI Emacs, `<tab>` is "translated" to `TAB` (see `C-h k <tab>` in a GUI).

In contrast, `TAB` is AFAICT completely equivalent to `C-i`.  In a terminal, when you press the Tab key, the terminal just sends the control character `C-i` and there's no way to distinguish between <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd>. (You can play around with `C-h k C-i` and `C-h k <tab>` in both the terminal and the GUI.)

In this case, since `org-cycle` is bound to `<tab>`, when you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> in GUI Emacs, it's immediately interpreted as `org-cycle`, and we never get to `TAB`.

When you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> in Terminal Emacs, it's sent by the terminal as `C-i` (`TAB`) to Emacs, and since Evil has priority over Org, it's interpreted as `evil-jump-forward`. (If you were to disable Evil, then `C-i` would run `org-cycle` because it'd no longer be shadowed by `evil-jump-forward`.)

### Disabling mapping of `evil-jump-forward`

You can use:

```
(setq evil-want-C-i-jump nil)
```

before `(require 'evil)` or `(use-package evil)`.

This will unfortunately disable the mapping everywhere (not just in Org files).

If you want to override the mapping just for Org files (and have it active in all other files), you could create your own keymap that overrides evil and that's only activated for Org files or perhaps try using evil-org (which creates such a keymap and does the override [for you](https://github.com/hlissner/evil-org-mode/blob/a9706da260c45b98601bcd72b1d2c0a24a017700/evil-org.el#L757). (note: I haven't tried it))

From [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28222/how-to-make-tab-work-in-org-mode-when-combined-with-evil-mode), you could also try:

```
(evil-define-key 'normal org-mode-map (kbd "<tab>") #'org-cycle)
```

Comment: Just a small comment on 2nd answer/suggestion:  when "TAB" is chosen (rather than "<tab>") then this works. In other words. `(evil-define-key 'normal org-mode-map (kbd "TAB") #'org-cycle)` works.